# please wait while jenkins is restarting

Tags: jenkins

It is taking too much time (waiting from last hours). I have only 1 project with multiple jobs. I have updated plugings regarind security issues and few updatest no luck. I have restarted jenkins many times and worked fine but now it stucks. Is there any way out to kill/suspend jenkins to avoid this wait

Answer (score 0):

After lot of reserach, I did not find any answer. So best way is to go to the jenkins folder in the drive, navigate to plugins directory and remove the folder which are installed and updated on the current date. Then strat teh jenkins and download the plugins which are deleted from the plugins folder